# Updating rows in a SQLite database using Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have the following problem:
I want to update an existing SQLite database row by row. What's happening now is that the iterator updates all existing rows with the last assigned value of `dbdata`.

I don't want that.
I want update `row 1` with the first assigned value of `dbdata`. Then take iterator shall go "up" again, get the next value and the updating should go on to the next row.
Obviously there is a problem with the logic but I cannot get my head around it.

Whats happening now is that the rows are updated now which leaves me with the last assigned value of `dbdata`for all rows. I only want one row to be updated per iteration.
How do I tell Python to always "go one row down"? Can someone give a hint? I am not looking for a complete solution here. My current code is as follows:

```
for row in dbconnector:
    print (row)
    dbdata = langid.classify("{}".format(row))
    print (dbdata)
    connector.execute('''update SOMEDB set test1=? , test2=?''',(dbdata[-2], dbdata[-1]))
```

I am working with a SQLite Database and Python 3.3.

Comment: Not sure I'm getting what you're trying to achieve but it would seem to me that all you need is a double loop: one to iterate over the various `row`s, the other to iterate over the values of your `dbdata` variable (array? list? tuple?).

Comment: @PriiduNeemre updated question. hope its clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Thanks for all the input!

```
n = 0
for row in dbconnector:
    print (row)
    dbdata = langid.classify("{}".format(row))
    print (dbdata)
        for amount in row:
        n += 1
        print (n)
        connector.execute('''update SOMEDB set test1=? , test2=? where rowid == ?''',(dbdata[-2], dbdata[-1], n))
```

That works! It alters with every iteration the number of the rowid.

Answer (score 1):

The reason all your data is set to the last dbdata is because your update isn't restricted to a single row so on each iteration all the rows are set to whatever dbdata you just processed. To restrict your update use a where clause so the only row affected is the one you want.

Comment: Yep. That is exactly the problem. I am aware of that. But I want all rows to be updated. First row with the first value of `dbdata`, second row with the second assigned value to `dbdata`. A where clause would restrict the process of updating to only one row, wouldnt it?

Comment: That's correct, that is what the loop is for. You update one row at a time, and then by looping through all the rows as you do, you set each row, it just happens one at a time.

Comment: Right now you change every row in somedb on each iteration of the loop. That is why all the values in somedb look like the last iteration of the loop. You need to just change one row per iteration of the loop.

Comment: thanks. I understand whats happening now but a `where` clause would restrict the updating process to only one row, right?

Comment: If it is hard coded. You need to have some way of identifying what row you want to update and then include that as part of the where clause. Some type of row count or something, I am not sure exactly what your table structure is so I can't say for sure but if the rows have a unique id that you can use that would be ideal. Essentially it needs to be a different where clause on each loop.

Comment: Yep. Thats exactly where I am stuck. All rows have an unique ID. But I dont know how to write something into the brackets `(dbdata[-2], dbdata[-1]))` to let them alter

Comment: "update somedb set test1=?, test2=? where rowid=?" I'm not sure where you would actually get the row id from, I don't have enough information about what you are trying to do to tell you exactly where to get it, but if it isn't in your dbdata then I'm not sure where you might get it.

Comment: Thats the problem. Where to get the rowid from? I was thinking about building an itertor `(dbdata[-2], dbdata[-1]))` into that part, or an if/else statement. But that seems rather hard.

Comment: Just get the id from the row object you iterating over, it doesn't have to be from dbdata now that I look at it. Do it like (dbdata[-1], dbdata[-2], row[0])) or whatever the index of the id is.

Comment: I set `n`to `0` and added this `(lan[-2], lan[-1], n + 1 if n <= 250 else n+0` but it does not work. Cause it always starts at 0 again. How would I get the number of iterations from `row`?

Comment: I believe the row should have the id stored in it. Access it like you access the parts of dbdata aka row[indexOfId]

Comment: Solved it. See my answer.